# How to restart a service in logrotate.conf

Tags: linux, shell, logrotate

I am having a script which is generating log in /var/log/venaqua. I want to manage that logs using logrotate. For that I am adding the following code in the /etc/logrotate.d/venaqua file

```
/var/log/venaqua{
    daily
    prerotate
        /bin/echo "`date` Starting Logrotate" >> /log/var/venaqua
    endscript
    rotate 5
    compress
    minsize 1M
    create 0644 root root
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl restart venaqua.service
        /bin/echo "`date` Logrotate Completed" >> /log/var/venaqua
    endscript
}
```

I am testing it by

```
sudo logrotate -v -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

and i am getting error as

```
rotating pattern: /var/log/venaqua forced from command line (5 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, only log files >= 1048576 bytes are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/venaqua
  Now: 2019-10-25 13:05
  Last rotated at 2019-10-25 12:49
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/venaqua, log->rotateCount is 5
dateext suffix '-20191025'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/venaqua.5.gz to /var/log/venaqua.6.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 5),
renaming /var/log/venaqua.4.gz to /var/log/venaqua.5.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 4),
renaming /var/log/venaqua.3.gz to /var/log/venaqua.4.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 3),
old log /var/log/venaqua.3.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/venaqua.2.gz to /var/log/venaqua.3.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 2),
old log /var/log/venaqua.2.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/venaqua.1.gz to /var/log/venaqua.2.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 1),
old log /var/log/venaqua.1.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/venaqua.0.gz to /var/log/venaqua.1.gz (rotatecount 5, logstart 1, i 0),
old log /var/log/venaqua.0.gz does not exist
running prerotate script
logrotate_script: 2: logrotate_script: cannot create /log/var/venaqua: Directory nonexistent
error: error running non-shared prerotate script for /var/log/venaqua of '/var/log/venaqua'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cannot create /log/var/venaqua: Directory nonexistent` tells it all. You have switched around `/var/log/` and `/log/var` in between your initial log definition `/var/log/venaqua{` and the subsequent path in your prerotate script, `>> /log/var/venaqua`. This error is also present in your postrotate script.

Comment: Now I don't get any errors but I am not getting what I want. That is my old rotated log is having only one line saying 
"Wed 30 Oct 10:07:03 IST 2019 Starting Logrotate"
All my log entries in that file are gone and replaced with this one line.
I am using >> to append but its replacing everything.

Comment: @Hari couldn't tell you off-hand. If you're still unsuccessful after trying to solve it you may want to post a new question.